# Squid webbased proxy authentication

Tags: squid

I am new with Squid, currently i have successfully setup basic authentication using external ACL to validate username and password. This works great, but I want to have a custom login page "HTML based" to authenticate a user.

Currently this is my setting that works:

```
auth_param basic program /usr/bin/php ./app.php
external_acl_type tcgloginhelper ttl=1800 %SRC %LOGIN %{Proxy-Authorization} /usr/bin/php ./app.php
acl tcglogin external tcgloginhelper
http_access allow tcglogin
```

Is it possible to have a custom html login page? How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to configure a custom login page to SQUID?

No. Squid uses the RFC-style Proxy-Authorization header. It gets a HTTP 
code 407 from the proxy and after a successful authentication delivers 
the header with every request. You would need to change both the proxy 
and the browser.

http://www.squid-cache.org/mail-archive/squid-users/200509/0251.html